# python 2.7 BeautifulSoup find the table containing a particular string

Tags: python-2.7, mechanize, beautifulsoup

After searching a BeautifulSoup document for a string, how do I get the table which contains that string? I have a solution which works on one table that I am familiar with:

My code is as follows:

```
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

sitemap_url = "https://www.rbi.org.in/scripts/sitemap.aspx"

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 
'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1'), 
('accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8')]

response = br.open(sitemap_url)
text = response.read()
br.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml')

# Find the table containing the financial intermediaries.

# First I find "Financial Intermediaries" in soup.
fin_str = soup.find(text="Financial Intermediaries")

# Next I step out through the parents 
# until it turns out that I have found the table.
fin_tbl = fin_str.parent.parent.parent.parent
```

The problem with this is that I have to check the results each time I step out of the document. How can I add .parent until I see the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append the following code onto the program:

```
# The first tag around the string is the parent.
fn_in = fin_str.parent

# Step out through the parents.
def step_out(i):
    if isinstance(i, element.NavigableString):
        pass
    return i.parent

# Continue until 'table' is in the name of the tag.
while not 'table' in fn_in.name:
    fn_in = step_out(fn_in)
```